# Как выбрать из 3х полей одно значение

Tags: sql, postgresql

Для элемента значение может хранится в одном из 3х полей, разных по типу (real, text, timestamp).

Одно гарантировано - значение есть в только в одном из полей.

Тип значения не знаю. То есть должно вернуться строковое значение из real, text или timestamp

на вскидку

```
SELECT COALESCE (dat.value::text,
                 COALESCE(dat.txtval,
                          dat.f_timestamp::text))
FROM vgok_site.a_analiz_data dat
WHERE dat.id = 20167
```

Comment: какого типа должна бить это результат?

Comment: А что у Вас с `coalesce` не вышло?

Comment: да все вышло. видать лучший вариант ибо с case не красиво

Comment: Только в `coalesce` не надо вставлять `coalesce` - эта функция принимает переменное число аргументов. Достаточно просто написать `coalesce(dat.value::text, dat.txtval, dat.f_timestamp::text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавлю, так же, изначальный вариант с `coalesce`. Эта функция принимает переменное число аргументов и возвращает первый из них, который не `null`.
В случае, как в этом примере, когда нужно перебрать несколько полей и вернуть первое не `null` значение она подходит в самый раз:

```
select coalesce (dat.value:;text, dat.txtval, dat.f_timestamp::text)
from vgok_site.a_analiz_data dat
where dat.id = 20167
```

А в случае когда все перечисленные поля имеют значение `null` и нужно вернуть какое-то значение по умолчанию - его можно просто добавить в конец списка аргументов функции `coalesce`:

```
coalesce (dat.value::text, dat.txtval, dat.f_timestamp::text, '0')
```

[Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3772).

Comment: не знал что можно использовать несколько параметров

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN value_real IS NOT NULL THEN to_char(value_real,'999D9')
  WHEN value_text IS NOT NULL THEN value_text
  WHEN value_time IS NOT NULL THEN to_char(value_time,'HH12:MI:SS')
  ELSE 0
END
FROM table
```

Comment: CASE types real and text cannot be matched

Comment: Не пойдет. В одной записи этот кейс вернет тип Real, в другой - text. И какой тип будет у поля в результате?

Comment: @des1roer изменил на текстовое поле, так как в вопросе вы тоже указали тип, проверьте

Comment: оно отработало. но с coalsece запись лаконичней я думаю

Comment: @des1roer это можно, но вы же проверили ну `NULL` если нужно тут можно и значение по умолчанию ставить через `ELSE`

Comment: мне null удобней обрабатывать чем если мне в поле календаря 0 прилетит

Comment: @des1roer ок это ваши условия.